# What is a good db for high update interval and aggregated reads?

Tags: sql, database, nosql

I need to find the solution for the following problem:

A system that has 10,000s of parent object, each one contains a few hundreds of sub types with valus which might be updated a few times each second.

On the other end, I need to generate aggregated data That can be calculated 4-5 times a second. There can be 10,000s of this different aggregators.

The good thing is that rows are rarely added during runtime, only updated. Also, the value types are small int and floats.

What framework should I use?

I thought about using a key-value nosql method, but that doesn't enables me to do aggregated calls. Any idea is welcome, thanks

Comment: Please give more details.  Is it *every* child node can be update several times a second? Or just 4-5 nodes out of those several million?  Is there a direct mapping between parent objects and aggregations (as the numbers imply)?  Are these aggregations simple counts, sums, etc or more complicated operations?

Comment: @APC each node may be updated and theres no direct link with the aggregators. Numbers may change. Also, only looking for sum and avg basically

Answer (score 1):

You should consider an OLAP solution, like SQL Server Analysis services. OLAP systems pre-calculate aggregations on several levels and facilitate therefore very high performance for scenarios such as yours.

Comment: Isn't it too much? Can it work efficiently real time? After all, I need aggregated info on a list of key-value pairs while olap and SQL analysis are designed for more complicated joins etc, isn't it?

Comment: Actually, aggregations are exactly what OLAP solutions are good at as opposed to OLTP systems. To requote from Wikipedia: "It has been claimed that for complex queries OLAP cubes can produce an answer in around 0.1% of the time for the same query on OLTP relational data". The update frequency may be an issue, but I believe that several OLAP implementations support partial recomputations in real-time

Comment: Am I right in understanding that you want sub-second latency between the data being updated and it being reflected in your aggregation queries? If so, then Analysis Services is out of the question. Consider a specialist CEP solution, such as StreamBase, OSISoft PI or possibly MS StreamInsight.

Comment: @dportas u r correct, and I think cep is what is was looking for. What do you think of open source cep like esper?

Comment: @AltControl, I'm not familiar with it. I think all the mainstream CEP players are not open source. Is there a some particular reason why open source interests you?